# how to rename files shared by some onedrive user with us, using microsoft graph apis

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, azure-ad-graph-api

I have a written code to rename files of onedrive logged in user, using graph api with following call.

```
www.graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/{FileOrFolderID}

with body:
{
"name":"newfilename.txt",
"@name.conflictBehavior": "rename"
}
```

I'm not able rename the files which has been shared by some other onedrive user with me, which I can if done in browser. The other user has given me editable permissions.

I have tried following syntax to rename file shared with me, but it gives me access denied error.

```
www.graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drives/{DriveId}/items/{FileOrFolderID}
```

Can someone please answer what thing I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to try:

1. Make sure you're requesting `Files.ReadWrite.All` if you need to modify someone else's items
2. Try hitting `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{DriveId}/items/{FileOrFolderID}`. Using "me" may work, but it's semantically weird.

If neither of those work please update your question to include the full response so we can debug further.

Comment: Adding permissions Files.ReadWrite.All worked for me.Thanks @Brad

Comment: the tag "@name.conflictBehavior": "rename" doesn't work, the request fails with an error : the name already exist.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try the character as follow, the full description refer to [Update DriveItem properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

This example renames the DriveItem resource to "new-file-name.docx".

PATCH /me/drive/items/{item-id}
Content-type: application/json

"name": "new-file-name.docx"

Regards,
Leon